# Piece stuck in LEGO T-Rex body part nr. 6223585

Tags: disassembly

My son stuck a rod piece through one of the openings in the T-Rex body middle part ([part# 6223585](https://rebrickable.com/parts/98160pr0003/animal-body-part-dinosaur-tyrannosaurus-rex-body-with-reddish-brown-and-dark-orange-skin-print/84/)). How can I open up the body to retrieve the rod piece?

The body is made of two parts that are clipped together I think. When looking inside, there seems to be a connection in the inside of the body as well.

Does anyone have experience with how to open up this piece with minimal damage?

The rod piece is completely inside the body piece, rattling around. He inserted it through the hole for the head or tail

Comment: You mean the element is not stuck, but instead has been pushed too far inside (since the hole for legs doesn't have anything to stop this from happening) and is now rattling inside?

Comment: OK, holes for head and tail could be to blame too as these are hollow as well.

Comment: The rod piece is completely inside the body piece, rattling around. He inserted it through the hole for the head or tail.

Comment: Just an idea that may not be very good: If you have some long/thin/pointy tweezers you might be able to grip the end of the axel inside two of the grooves along the side and pull it out. That's assuming you can get the axel into a place you can do that, I don't have the piece to know how likely that is.

Comment: Given that you can't see inside the piece, and that the two arms of the tweezers will have to be quite close together to even get in through one of the holes, I don't think that will be easy. I have no experience with the procedure, but I think the trick to get a cork ut of a bottle (there are many videos online of it) might be the way to go.

Comment: I just succeeded. I have shaken the body piece continually untill, by pure chance, the rod piece somehow aligned with the hole again, and came out.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

How to get a part out of TRexBod:
https://youtu.be/wHsnLP1xuHY

Comment: Hi arilou and welcome to Bricks.SE! As far as I can see your method was successful and thus it is an answer to the question, but it'd enormously benefit from a short summary of the tools and methods used (maybe with some still images uploaded directly to Bricks.SE), as there is no guarantee that the YouTube link will be available always to everyone. Can you please do that or do you have any questions regarding it?